# Mapping Querystring Parameters to Resource Methods in JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

Amazon's web API uses a "query API" for non-CRUD operations by using a querystring parameter to specify the operation.  I want to implement non-CRUD operations in a similar manner.

Is there any way to map a POST resource method using Jersey JAX-RS dependent on the value of a particular querystring parameter?  For example I would like to do something like this:

```
@POST @Query(name="xaction", value="move") 
public Response move(@QueryParam("source") String source, @QueryParam("dest") String dest)
{
...
}

@POST @Query(name="xaction", value="copy")
public Response copy(@QueryParam("source") String source, @QueryParam("dest") String dest)
{
...
}
```

In the above example I would expect a framework would dispatch to the appropriate method depending on the value of the "xaction" querystring parameter regardless of URI path.  Unfortunately I do not have the luxury of using paths or methods to distinguish these operations.  I am open to other library suggestions that are compatible with JAX-RS or custom implementations to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST is not Remote Procedure Call (RPC). Even if Amazon is publishing an API like this, it is still not RESTful.

JAX-RS does not provide a mapping you describe for good reasons. Every Resource must be uniquely identifiable by the URI which includes the full path and all query parameters. URI like you describe don't identify Resources but call *procedures*.

Ask yourself these questions:

1. What are your Resources?
2. Do actions on Resources easily map to HTTP verbs?
3. If not, can actions on Resources me modeled as Resources?

As example for 3., you could thing about a `MoveResource` and a `CopyReource`.

A JSON Representation of a `MoveResource` could look like this:

```
{
  "source": "/path/to/source",
  "dest": "/path/to/dest"
}
```

Creating such a `MoveResource` and thus triggering a move could be done by a `POST` to the collection Resource at `/moves`. This `POST` would return `201 Created` with a `Location` header like `/moves/42`. A `GET` to *this* Resource could return the state of the `MoveResource`:

```
{
  "source": "/path/to/source",
  "dest": "/path/to/dest",
  "status": "success"
}
```

The same could be done for a `CopyResource`.